# How to clear the data of new row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I am adding new rows like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(2);
var colCount = table.rows[3].cells.length;
for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
  var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
  newcell.innerHTML = able.rows[3].cells[i].innerHTML;
}
```

I don't want to loose input field data when refresh is done so, I use php session like these:

```
isset($_POST['details'])?$_SESSION['details'] = $_POST['details']:$_SESSION['details']="";
```

when I refresh and return same page session hold the previous data.

 My problem is when i click **add row button** it generates same(previously inserted) data in new row also.

So I want to ask *how to clear the data in new row*. I think I need to have some code here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
```

> //need some code here to clear the field in newly created fields

```
  var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
  newcell.innerHTML = able.rows[3].cells[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you are probably looking for `unset()`, unset can unset any variable including global variables like `SESSION`.

Comment: no, I can't unset the session I need to clear data when the new input field is create

Comment: Are you talking about Javascript here? Then you can just set the value to nothing right?

Comment: @Jordy, nope, he Shrestha not looking to clear session data. Actually he making clone of html fields and in that old data also get added

Comment: So there's your answer right xd

Comment: I don't want to clear the session and set the value of new field to nothing